# Is there a name for questions where the answer is not important?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, questions

A question where you don't care about the answer.

e.g. "how are you today?" where you don't actually care what the answer is. Is it a polite question?

Comment: "Greeting question," perhaps. However, that's only considering a wishing/greeting like "How are you!" There are other questions that do not expect an answer, called rhetorical questions. Please also visit [ell.se]

Comment: @Kris Why would this native speaker need to go to ELL to find out about meta-language? I don't understand ... :(

Comment: @Araucaria I never think ELL is for non-native speakers alone *per se* -- it's for **all** learners (esp., non-native speakers, if you please).  :)

Answer (score 0):

A [cliché](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Clich%C3%A9)  or a set phrase:

> - (Linguistics) a word or expression that has lost much of its force through overexposure.

Answer (score 0):

A formality? We exchanged the usual formalities.

Comment: No; this is not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

phatic talk is the phrase you're looking for

Comment: Please give a rationale for your answer.

Comment: Whilst your answer is linguistically correct, you should always back up your statement. Especially when suggesting a term that is most likely not common knowledge - I did google, others may not.